# Issue with jQuery class

Tags: jquery

There is an checkBox on the page

```
   <input 
       name='<%=htmlServiceId %>' 
       <%--class='parent-<%= service.ParentId.Value.GetCustomerServiceId() %>'--%>
       class='parent-<%=service.ParentId.Value.GetCustomerCategoryId() %> x-form-checkbox x-form-field'
       type='checkbox' 
       id="<%=htmlServiceId%>"
     />
```

Here is how the result html looks

```
<input name="s8" class="parent-s18" id="s8" type="checkbox"/>
```

Before when checkBos had one class (`parent-sXX`) I find this checkBox (and others like this) by this way

```
//........................
var temp = $(this).attr('class').split('-');
  var parentId = temp[1];
  if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
                $('#' + parentId).attr('checked', 'checked');
                //.......................
 }
```

}

But now the checkBox has several classes (`parent-sXX x-form-checkbox x-form-field` ) and this solution by finding checkBox by class doesn't work.

How to fix it?

UPDATE: is there any way except using `data` attribute?

Comment: Split the classes output (parent-sXX x-form-checkbox x-form-field) by the "space" character - then remove all who dosent contain "parent-" - and use your normal code? :)

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Show me an, please.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the data method?

Comment: Because it's not a complete code. I have to use class, but not data.

Comment: @AlexMaslakov See my updated answer for a solution without using data attributes. (Very similar to Marco's comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to maintain your original code, you can just filter out the class.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/mSRZY/

```
$(':checkbox').change( function() {

    //get classes
    var getClass = $(this).attr('class');
    //seperate them into an array
    var classes = getClass.split(' ');

    //loop the array, replace getClass if it find the "search param"
    $.each(classes, function(index,value) {
        if(value.indexOf("parent") != -1) {
            getClass = value;
        }
    });

    alert(getClass);
});
```

Comment: You should proberbly insert it into a new var instead of getClass, so you can check if it is found or not :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to just add another `data-` attribute and use that instead of trying to extract the id from one of the classes..

```
  <input 
       name='<%=htmlServiceId %>' 
       <%--class='parent-<%= service.ParentId.Value.GetCustomerServiceId() %>'--%>
       class='parent-<%=service.ParentId.Value.GetCustomerCategoryId() %> x-form-checkbox x-form-field'
       type='checkbox' 
       data-parentid="<%= service.ParentId.Value.GetCustomerServiceId() %>"
       id="<%=htmlServiceId%>"
     />
```

and use

```
var parentId = $(this).data( 'parentid' );
if ( $(this).attr('checked')) {
                $('#' + parentId).attr('checked', 'checked');
```

---

**Update**

Since you cannot use `data` here is a way to split the classes ..

```
var itemClasses = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
var parentId = '';

for (var i = 0; i < itemClasses.length; i++) {
    if (itemClasses[i].indexOf('parent-s') == 0) {
        parentId = itemClasses[i].split('-')[1];
        break;
    }
}

if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
    $('#' + parentId).attr('checked', 'checked');
}
```

Comment: @alex, updated  answer with a way to find the class and split it as you were doing initially..

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to keep your HTML as is, this should obtain the number you require from the list of classes -

```
var parentId = $(this).attr('class').match(/parent-s(\d+)/)[1];
  if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
                $('#' + parentId).attr('checked', 'checked');
                //.......................
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use data attributes and the jQuery [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method:

HTML

```
<input 
   name='<%=htmlServiceId %>' 
   class='x-form-checkbox x-form-field'
   type='checkbox' 
   id="<%=htmlServiceId%>"
   data-parentId="<%=service.ParentId.Value.GetCustomerCategoryId() %>"
 />
```

JS

```
var parentId = $(this).data('parentId');
if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
    $('#' + parentId).attr('checked', 'checked');
}
```

Without using data attributes you can do this:

```
var temp = $(this).attr('class').split(' '), parentId;
for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    if (temp[i].indexOf('parent-') === 0) {
         parentId = temp[i].split('-')[1];
    }
}
if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
    $('#' + parentId).attr('checked', 'checked');
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/BenMB/)